# How to Get Data from index of String

Tags: c#

I'm new in c#. and I have some Question...

I have String following this code

```
string taxNumber = "1222233333445";
```

I want to get data from This string like that

```
string a = "1"
string b = "2222"
string c = "33333"
string d = "44"
string e = "5"
```

Please Tell me about Method for get Data From String.

Thank You Very Much ^^

Comment: what you have tried???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the String.Substring(int index, int length) method

```
string a = taxNumber.Substring(0, 1);
string b = taxNumber.Substring(1, 4);
// etc
```

Answer (score 3):

Oh well, the best I can come up with is this:

```
IEnumerable<string> numbers
    = taxNumber.ToCharArray()
               .Distinct()
               .Select(c => new string(c, taxNumber.Count(t => t == c)));

foreach (string numberGroup in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numberGroup);
}
```

Outputs:

```
1 
2222 
33333 
44 
5
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also do  , you dont need to fix the no of characters, you can check by changing the no of 1's , 2's etc

```
string taxNumber = "1222233333445";
           string s1 = taxNumber.Substring(taxNumber.IndexOf("1"), ((taxNumber.Length - taxNumber.IndexOf("1")) - (taxNumber.Length - taxNumber.LastIndexOf("1"))) + 1);
           string s2 = taxNumber.Substring(taxNumber.IndexOf("2"), ((taxNumber.Length - taxNumber.IndexOf("2")) - (taxNumber.Length - taxNumber.LastIndexOf("2"))) + 1);
           string s3 = taxNumber.Substring(taxNumber.IndexOf("3"), ((taxNumber.Length - taxNumber.IndexOf("3")) - (taxNumber.Length - taxNumber.LastIndexOf("3"))) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Char.IsDigit` to identify digits out of string, and may apply further logic as follows:

```
 for (int i=0; i< taxNumber.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(taxNumber[i]))
          {
                  if(taxNumber[i-1]==taxNumber[i])
                   {
                     /*Further assign values*/ 
                   }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Code**

```
    string taxNumber = "1222233333445";           

    char[] aa = taxNumber.ToCharArray();
    List<string> finals = new List<string>();

    string temp = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < aa.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            temp = aa[i].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            if (aa[i].ToString() == aa[i - 1].ToString())
            {
                temp += aa[i];
            }
            else
            {
                if (temp != string.Empty)
                {
                    finals.Add(temp);
                    temp = aa[i].ToString();
                }
            }
            if (i == aa.Length - 1)
            {
                if (aa[i].ToString() != aa[i - 1].ToString())
                {
                    temp = aa[i].ToString();
                    finals.Add(temp);
                }
                else
                {
                    finals.Add(temp);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

and check value of finals string list

Answer (score 0):

you may use regex:

```
string strRegex = @"(1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+|0+)";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"1222233333445";

return myRegex.Split(strTargetString);
```